# How to print to screen from inside a Fortran program that is called via f2py, inside the IPython Notebook?

Tags: python, fortran, ipython, jupyter-notebook, f2py

Say inside *test_fortran_module.f90* there is defined a subroutine

```
subroutine sum2numbers(x, y, z)
  implicit none
  real, intent(in) :: x, y
  real, intent(out) :: z

  write (*, *) 'z = x + y'
  z = x + y
end subroutine sum2numbers
```

and I compile it using f2py:

```
f2py3 -c test_fortran_module.f90 -m test_fortran_module
```

Inside IPython (the interactive prompt),

```
In [26]: import test_fortran_module

In [27]: z = test_fortran_module.sum2numbers(7, 6)
 z = x + y
```

it is seen that 'z = x + y' is printed.  But if the same thing is done in a IPython notebook,

[image]

'z = x + y' is not printed.  Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584787/the-stdout-stderr-in-python-notebooks , but now answer there, just some links and hints, which could be made into an answer with some effort.

Comment: I meant *no* answer there.

Comment: We (Jupyter) are now working on a proposal that would let us capture output at the OS level, which would fix this. In the meantime, the links and hints on the previous question can be hammered into something to do it, at least on Unix systems.

Comment: @ThomasK: `os.dup2()` should work on Windows too. Though [I haven't tested it personally](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22434262/4279)

Comment: @ThomasK: this seems to be working in the notebook by now. But is there also a version that doesn't only flush all output only at the end?